# axios and mongo - trying to delete using the mapped _id as the perimeter. It responds with 200 but object remains in the db

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, mongoose, axios

Trying to make a simple CRUD app using react, axios and mongoose.

**Here is my axios:**

```
deleteUser(id) {
    axios.delete(`${rootUrl}/api/users/${this.state.id}`, {
        params: { id }
    })
    .then(response => {
        // this.setState({ users: response.data });
        console.log('deleteUser response', response, this.state);
    });
}
```

**Here is the relevant API route:**

```
router.delete('/users/', (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.body;

    User.findByIdAndDelete(id, (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log('error in deleting!');
            throw error;
        } else {
            console.log('user has been deleted', data);
            res.status(204).json(data);
        }
    });
});
```

**It returns**

```
DELETE /api/users/?id=5b34e5b5dfef8b4sd234567 204 47.816 ms - -
```

But when I GET users, the deleted user remains.

**Here is the render I am mapping state into.** I think I am pulling the id in properly but I am not sure what else to try:

```
{this.state.users.map(user => {
    return (
        <div className="Users1" key={user._id}>
            <Card>
                <CardBody>
                    <CardTitle>{user.username}</CardTitle>
                    <CardText>{user._id}</CardText>

                    <Button onClick={() => this.deleteUser(user._id)}
                            key={user._id}
                            type="button"
                            color="danger"
                    >
                        X
                    </Button>
                </CardBody>
            </Card>
        </div>       
    );
})}
```

**and here is state:**

```
state = {
    users: [],
    id: ''
};
```

Comment: can you log `req.body`?

Comment: When I log req.body, server-side, it returns an empty object {}

Comment: Curiously enough, if I use Postman to delete by using the id as an object in the body, then logging req.body does show the id, but it still doesn't get deleted.

Comment: There's definitely something wrong from the client side.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I had success by looking at the req.query property on the API server, rather than req.body:

```
const { id } = req.query;
```

I figured it out by dumping the entire req object to the console.

On the client side, my request did not include the id in the URL. I just included it in the params object. This seemed to help. So the equivalent call in your code would look something like this:

```
axios.delete(`${rootUrl}/api/users/`, {
    params: { id }
})
```

I hope this helps. I'm still just learning React Native, so I'm hardly an expert. But I wanted to share what worked for me in case it helps others.